# Approximating and simplifying an electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, approximations

I calculated the electric field exerted by a square lying on the $xy$ plane with side length $a$ on a random point in space $(x,y,z)$, and got this expression:
$$\vec{E}=\frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}\frac{(x-\tilde{x})\hat{x}+(y-\tilde{y})\hat{y}+z\hat{z}}{((x-\tilde{x})^{2}+(y-\tilde{y})^{2}+z^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}d\tilde{x}d\tilde{y}.$$
Now I wanted to make an approximation to the electric field far away from the square, meaning $r\gg a$ where $r$ is the distance from the origin.  I expect to get an electric field of a point charge in the origin with the charge of the whole square. How would you go about it? I tried defining $\varepsilon=\frac{a}{r}$ and using taylor series to approximate but I get to nothing. Is this the right way to tackle these kind of problems?

**I'm not asking for a full solution, and it's not a solve my homework kind of post. I often fall into trouble trying to take different limits to answers. This is just a single example to work with and hopefully be able to apply the techniques in many different kind of problems I face in physics.**

Comment: So, to be clear, you're not looking for higher-order corrections, just the point-charge result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\vec{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}=r\hat{r}$ and $\vec{\tilde{r}}=\tilde{x}\hat{x}+\tilde{y}\hat{y}$. Then the integrand becomes

$$\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}+z\hat{z}}{(|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

Since the square of charge is far away from the origin, when the point $(x,y,z)$ is very far from the square of charge, it will also be very far from the origin. In that case, then one or more of the following must be true:

- $r\gg a$
- $z\gg0$

So there are three cases: 1) $r$ is big and $z$ is small, 2) $z$ is big and $r$ is small, 3) both $r$ and $z$ are big.

---

If $r\gg a$, then it must be true that $\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}\approx \vec{r}$. To prove this, we first use the Law of Cosines:

$$|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|^2=r^2+\tilde{r}^2-2r\tilde{r}\cos{\theta}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. Since we know that $r\gg a$, we also know that $r\gg \tilde{r}$, so $r^2\gg \tilde{r}^2$ and $r^2\gg r\tilde{r}$. This means that $|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|\approx r$.

Likewise, to calculate the direction of the resultant unit vector, we can use the Law of Sines:

$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\tilde{r}}=\frac{\sin\theta}{|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|}$$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\hat{r}$ and the new unit vector. We already know that $|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|\approx r$, so:

$$\sin\alpha\approx\frac{\tilde{r}}{r}\sin\theta$$

Since we also know that $\tilde{r}<a$, so $\frac{\tilde{r}}{r}\ll1$, we therefore have that, to first order,

$$\sin\alpha\approx 0$$

Since $\alpha$ was the angle between $\hat{r}$ and the new resultant vector, we can now say that the resultant's unit vector is approximately $\hat{r}$. So it has a magnitude of $r$ and a direction of $\hat{r}$, meaning that $\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}\approx\vec{r}$.

If we plug that in to the original expression, we get (when $r$ is big):

$$\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}+z\hat{z}}{(|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\approx \frac{\vec{r}+z\hat{z}}{(r^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

No matter what size $z$ is, this is now identical to the expression for a point charge in cylindrical coordinates. Since the integrand is now constant, integrating it now reduces to multiplying by $a^2$. So this covers the first and third cases.

---

For the second case, when $r$ is small but $z$ is big, the following must be true:

- $z\gg x$
- $z\gg y$
- $z\gg \tilde{x}$
- $z\gg \tilde{y}$

This also means that $z\gg(x-\tilde{x})$ and $z\gg(y-\tilde{y})$. By a similar procedure as the above, you can prove using the Law of Cosines and Law of Sines that $(\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}})+z\hat{z}\approx z\hat{z}$, which also means that $|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|^2+z^2\approx z^2$. Plugging these in, we have that:

$$\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}+z\hat{z}}{(|\vec{r}-\vec{\tilde{r}}|^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\approx \frac{z\hat{z}}{(z^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{\hat{z}}{z^2}$$

which is exactly the expression for a point charge along the $z$ axis. Since the integrand is, again, a constant, integrating amounts to multiplying by the integration area $a^2$.